# Probability summation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

[image]

Hello, 
I do not understand the sums and products section of probability at all. Can you explain how to solve this problem? Any resources where advanced summation, series, product is explained in a simple language?

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity
$$
\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{j}=\binom{n}{j}\binom{n-j}{m-j};\quad n\geq m\geq j\geq 0
$$
to write the general term as
$$
\binom{k}{1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k-1}{2}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom{k-1}{2}=n\binom{n-1}{2}\binom{n-3}{k-3}\quad k\geq 3
$$
and then apply the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

What are we counting here?

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom k1\binom {k-1}2\binom{n}k$$
This counts the ways to select a team of $k$ from $n$ applicants, among which you select a team captain and two lieutenants; summing the count for all possible values of $k$. ($3\leq k\leq n$ actually, because $\binom k1\binom{k-1}2$ is zero for $k$ of $0,1$ or $2$)

So count ways to select a captain and two lieutenants from among the $n$ applicants, multiplying this by the summed count of all the ways to select the rest of the team of $k$ from the $n-3$ remaining. ($0\leq k\leq n-3$)

> You can do it!  We are selecting $1$ from $n$, $2$ from $n-1$, and for $0\leq k\leq n-3$ selecting $k$ from $n-3$.

---

PS: The binomial theorem will be handy simplifying the result.  Alternatively the count for ways to select the rest of the team is the count for subsets of a set of size $n-3$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{k-1}{2}\binom{n}{k} 
&= \sum_{k=3}^n k \binom{k-1}{2}\binom{n}{k} \\
&= 3\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{k}{3}\binom{k-1}{2}\binom{n}{k}\\
&= 3\sum_{k=3}^n \binom{k}{3}\binom{n}{k}\\
&= 3\sum_{k=3}^n \binom{n}{3}\binom{n-3}{n-k}\\
&= 3 \binom{n}{3}\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n-3}{n-k}\\
&= 3 \binom{n}{3}\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{n-3}{k-3}\\
&= 3 \binom{n}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{n-3}\binom{n-3}{k}\\
&= 3 \binom{n}{3}2^{n-3}\\
&= 3 \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}2^{n-3}\\
&= n(n-1)(n-2)2^{n-4}
\end{align}